# Convert mongo objectid to string using rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query, rmongodb

I'm trying to convert a mongo collection to an R data frame.
I'm using rmongodb package to do the same.
I'm facing a problem with fields with the datatype "ObjectId" (in the code below, the column "_id"), rmongodb does not seem to recognize them as valid fields and thus excluding them from the OP dataframe. Is there a way to bulk convert ObjectId fields to string or extract their values?

```
query <- list(
mongo.bson.from.JSON('
{
"$project" : {
"_id" :0,
"app_id" : "$_id",
"column_1" : "$mongo_column_1",
#########################
```

I've already tried the functions:

```
ObjectId.toString()
```

and

```
ObjectId.valueOf()
```

But I think I'm making some syntactical errors and can't seem to find the right syntax to work in this situation.

P.S. I'm parsing the entire collection and not individual records.

Comment: What are you currently getting back to **R** when you're not using toString/valueOf?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, the entire oid column just gets skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning. Try using the [mongo.oid.to.string](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rmongodb/docs/mongo.oid.to.string) function.

```
l = mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor))

k <- mongo.oid.to.string(l[["_id"]])
k
"5242aef73edb350519b2bf3f"
```